No option for linux mint in virtual machine manager
I am trying to create a linux mint virtual machine using virtual machine manager. I'm using the linuxmint-21.3-cinnamon-64bit.iso image. However, when I try to find mint in the "choose the operating system you are installing" section it doesn't show mint as an option (the automatic detection also don't work). This seems strange as more obscure distros such as nix show up as options.
Should linux mint be showing up as an option or am I experiencing some kind of error and if not what operating system should I select here.
P.S.
I am new to virtual machines and still fairly new to linux so while I don't think this is a duplicate there is a change I'm missing something which is obvious to the experienced. If that is so please at least point me in the right direction before close/down vote bombing this question.

Just choose any 64bit Linux, it should not really matter.

It would help to know which virtual product you're using.
In general, the choice of the operating system when creating the VM
is immaterial.
It's useful to choose one that is of the same general family as your
installation media, meaning Linux/Windows (for VMware you don't even
need to choose between 32/64-bit), although even that is not very
important.

I'm using KVM My main system is also running linux mint
